# Count the Number of unique pairs differ by 1 in 2 integer array

Tags: java

Dancing Pair

Delhi Public School is hosting a chess competition in celebration of its 30th anniversary. N boys and M girls registered for it. The school management has to make pairs(since chess is a 2 people game).

A pair must have one boy and one girl. However, the partners’ chess skills in each pair must differ by at most one.
For each boy, we know his chess skills. Similarly, for each girl, we know her chess skills.

You being in the management committee has to determine the largest possible number of pairs that can be formed from N boys and M girls.

Input:
The first line contains T- denoting the number of test cases.
For each Test Case in T,

```
The first line contains a single integer N, denoting the number of boys.
The second line contains N space-separated integers denoting skills of N boys.
The third line contains a single integer M, denoting the number of girls.
The fourth line contains M space-separated integers denoting skills of M girls.
```

Output:
Output in the new line the maximum number of pairs that can be formed wherein each pair the skill of the boy and the girl differ by at most 1.

Constraints:

```
1<=N<=1e5
1<=M<=1e5
0<=1e9<=skills.
```

Sample Input:

```
2
3
1 2 3
3
2 3 4
4
2 3 4 5
3
6 7 8
```

Sample output:

```
3
1
```

Explanation:

In the first test case, the 1st boy can be paired with 1st girl(difference in skills=1),2nd boy with 2nd girl(difference in skills=1), and 3rd boy with 3rd girl(difference in skills=1).
We can see every pair has at most 1 difference in the skills of their partners.
In the second test case, only the 3rd boy and 1st girl can be paired(difference in skills=1), for every other pair the difference will be greater than 1.

Sample Input:

```
2
3
3 6 7 
4
7 5 7 10 
3
2 9 1 
5
2 7 2 7 11
```

Output:

```
2
2
```

**My solution, but it is passing only 2 out-off 4 test cases and i dont have other test cases input so can u guys tell where can be the mistake and this need to be done in java only**

```
//import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.IOException;
//import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arrgs) throws IOException {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
//        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//        String[] strNumsBoys ;
//        String[] strNumsGirls ;

        ArrayList<Integer> all = new ArrayList<>();
        int t = obj.nextInt();
        while (t != 0) {
            int count = 0;
            int numberOfBoys = obj.nextInt();
//                strNumsBoys = bi.readLine().split("\\s");
//                for (int i = 0; i < strNumsBoys.length; i++) {
//                    boysSkills[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNumsBoys[i]);
//                }
//            strNumsBoys = obj.nextLine().split("\\s");
//            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBoys; i++) {
//                boysSkills[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNumsBoys[i]);
//            }
            int[] boysSkills = new int[numberOfBoys];

            for(int i=0;i<numberOfBoys;i++)
            {
                boysSkills[i] = obj.nextInt();

            }
            int numberOfGirls = obj.nextInt();
//            strNumsGirls = bi.readLine().split("\\s");
//            for (int i = 0; i < strNumsGirls.length; i++) {
//                girlsSkills[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNumsGirls[i]);
//            }
//            strNumsGirls = obj.nextLine().split("\\s");
//            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGirls; i++) {
//                girlsSkills[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNumsGirls[i]);
//            }
            int[] girlsSkills = new int[numberOfGirls];
            for(int i=0;i<numberOfGirls;i++)
            {
                girlsSkills[i] = obj.nextInt();

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBoys; i++) {
                int incresed = boysSkills[i];
                incresed = incresed + 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < numberOfGirls; k++) {
                    if (incresed == girlsSkills[k]) {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            int out = count;
            all.add(out);
            t = t - 1;
        }
        all.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken these 2 cases:

1. when boysSkills[i]==girlsSkills[i] since the difference is almost 1.
2. a decreased variable also since the difference is asked and it can be positive or negative.